# Understanding SVN error : Reintegrate can only be used if

Tags: svn, merge

Doing a SVN merge from **pre_prod** branche to **b1** branche I get following error:

```
D:\Web\projet\branches>svn merge svn://10.10.10.10/projet/branches/pre_prod b1
svn: E195016: Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 239 through 259 were previously 
merged from svn://10.10.10.10/projet/branches/b1 to
the reintegrate source, but this is not the case:
  branches/pre_prod
    Missing ranges: /branches/pre_prod:241,245
  branches/pre_prod/src/Type
    Missing ranges: /branches/pre_prod/src/Type:245
```

I want to try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13409835/2814253) from SO.

But I've a difference with his case, his error says:

```
branches/bronze_services/occl
    Missing ranges: /trunk/occl:650-693
```

Which are two different branches, whereas my error says me to merge pre_prod branches with itself. How is it possible?

Moreover my error message says to merge missing revisions *from svn://10.10.10.10/projet/branches/b1*.

I don't understand it, what should I merge and from where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok actually I just need to re-use the initial command which throws the error, and add manually the revision missing as says in the error message:

The following command throws an error:

```
svn merge svn://10.10.10.10/projet/branches/pre_prod b1
svn: E195016: Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 239 through 259 were previously [...]
```

So just replay the merge as following:

```
svn merge -r 239:259 svn://10.10.10.10/projet/branches/pre_prod b1
```

Comment: Interesting. This worked for me, unlike all others solutions.

Comment: You got lucky (or you had to resolve conflicts); the second merge is not the same as the first merge and is not the solution.  If you read the error message more carefully you would have seen that it actually asked you to merge r239:259 from b1 to pre_prod, not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to work around the same error message by:

1. Making a fresh check-out of trunk: `svn co ${SVN_URL}/trunk`
2. Merging the branch from the repository into the fresh check-out: `cd trunk && svn merge ${SVN_URL}/branches/the_branch`

You should of course commit the merged check-out.