# Reintegrate can only be used if revisions [...] were previously merged from svn://... to the reintegrate source : which source?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I try to merge from a production branche into a development branch in order to reintegrate other developpers' changes, but I get the following error:

```
Command: Auto-merge svn://10.33.1.1/myPortail/branches/preproduction into F:\Web\myPortail\branches\branche1  
Error: Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 239 through 359 were previously  
Error:  merged from svn://10.33.1.1/myPortail/branches/branche1 to the  
Error:  reintegrate source, but this is not the case:  
Error:   branches/preproduction  
Error:     Missing ranges:  
Error:  /branches/pre_prod:286,288-289,292,294,296,300,302,305,308,310,314,317,322-323,325,331,339,341,343,345,347,349,351,353,356,358  
Error:   
Error:   branches/preproduction/src/Module/Admin/views/ccManagment/ccEdit.twig  
Error:     Missing ranges:  
Error:  /branches/preproduction/src/Module/Admin/views/ccManagment/ccEdit.twig:286,322
```

I want to try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13409835/2814253) from SO, but I don't understand which branch should be merged into which one.

I execute following merge as I understand the error message:

```
svn merge -r 239:359 svn://10.33.1.1/myPortail/branches/branche1 preproduction
```

But it changes nothing... How do you understand the error and where do I need to merge to and from?